# UnitOfWork - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing session transaction state (false) does not match requested (true)

Tags: hibernate, dropwizard, aspect

After upgrading the dropwizard to 2.0.25, I am started getting this exception in the methods  having @unitOfwork annotations ,

Can you help me out to rectify these errors ?
why I am getting these errors now ?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing session transaction state (false) does not match requested (true)
at io.dropwizard.hibernate.UnitOfWorkAspect.validateSession(UnitOfWorkAspect.java:178)
at io.dropwizard.hibernate.UnitOfWorkAspect.beforeStart(UnitOfWorkAspect.java:85)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
Add `ManagedSessionContext.unbind(sessionFactory)` to the end of your authenticator's authenticate method (right before/after closing the session).

**Long answer:**
After upgrading to Dropwizard 2.0.32, I was also having this exact problem - resource methods with `@UnitOfWork` annotations were throwing the exception you posted, with the same message. However, these methods also all had a parameter with the `@Auth` annotation, and I was able to determine that the problem only occurred when *both* annotations were present.

The authenticate method in my authenticator had the following structure.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
// Do stuff using the session
session.close();
```

When I changed it to the following, the problem was resolved.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
// Do stuff using the session
ManagedSessionContext.unbind(sessionFactory);
session.close();
```